# Remove list of word from string using python

Tags: python, str-replace

I am trying to remove a list of words from a string using python. I tried the code below, but it is adding space while replacing words in the string. Is there any approach which helps to remove only the word present in the list of words? Please give me some advice.

```
words_to_remove=['gosh', 'no', 'oh', 'Yep', 'ow', 'well', 'goodness', 'Yeah']

test_data = """RegExr Yeah was created by gskinner.com.
yippe, ow, ouch, gosh Yeah oh, goodness, oh well, oh no, how can I do wonders in this world. Yep, it is out of the world.
Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
"""

# Remove words
for word in words_to_remove:
    test_data = test_data.replace(word, '')

test_data
Out[46]: 'RegExr  was created by gskinner.com.\nyippe, , ouch,   , ,  ,  , h can I do wonders in this world. , it is out of the world.\nEdit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.\nThe side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.\nExplore results with the Tools bel. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.\n'
```

Comment: It's not *adding* a space, you're just not *removing* the adjacent space…

Comment: It's in fact somewhat complex, as you'll want to remove *some* spaces but not others, i.e. the rules are different for the start of a sentence and around punctuation. Even more complex if you want to remove commas in a now empty listing…

Comment: if should be matching criteria, like full match or semi match, in semi match, word to remove does partial matching count like for word `goshing` should this be remove ?

Comment: Does no one else feel like this is actually a somewhat clever attempt at advertising a website rather than a genuine question?

Comment: @Julien now you have mentioned it , it seem more an  advertisement

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the offending words, you might use regular expressions and compile a pattern from your list of words to rmeove.

```
>>> r = re.compile(rf"\b(?:{'|'.join(words_to_remove)})\b")
>>> r.sub('', test_data)
'RegExr  was created by gskinner.com.\nyippe, , ouch,   , ,  ,  , how can I do wonders in this world. , it is out of the world.\nEdit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.\nThe side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.\nExplore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.\n'
```

Now this clearly doesn't address the excessive punctuation, but your can probably solve that with a regex. An initial take that you can likely improve.

```
>>> re.sub(r'([,.:;?]\s?)[\s,.:;?]*', r'\1', r.sub('', test_data))
'RegExr  was created by gskinner.com.\nyippe, ouch, how can I do wonders in this world. it is out of the world.\nEdit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.\nThe side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.\nExplore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.\n'
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, seems this is working as expected , double space that appeared while replacing Yeah in "RegExr Yeah was created" any idea what could have caused. As it seems it replace correctly for remaining words in list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `strip(',')` for each word if it's not in `words_to_remove`

```
words_to_remove=['gosh', 'no', 'oh', 'Yep', 'ow', 'well', 'goodness', 'Yeah']

test_data = """RegExr Yeah was created by gskinner.com.
yippe, ow, ouch, gosh Yeah oh, goodness, oh well, oh no, how can I do wonders in this world. Yep, it is out of the world.
Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
"""

# Remove words
test_data = ' '.join(filter(lambda i: i.strip(',') not in words_to_remove, test_data.split(' ')))

print(test_data)
```

Output:

```
RegExr was created by gskinner.com.
yippe, ouch, how can I do wonders in this world. it is out of the world.
Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
words_to_remove = ['gosh', 'no', 'oh', 'Yep', 'ow', 'well', 'goodness', 'Yeah']

test_data = """RegExr Yeah was created by gskinner.com.
yippe, ow, ouch, gosh Yeah oh, goodness, oh well, oh no, how can I do wonders in this world. Yep, it is out of the world.
Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
"""

splitted = test_data.split(' ')
filtered = list(filter(lambda word: word not in words_to_remove, splitted))
print(' '.join(filtered))
```

Comment: Does not work with commas....

Answer (score -1):

string are immutable, so dont use replace and keep making new list again adn again

```
words_to_remove=set(['gosh', 'no', 'oh', 'Yep', 'ow', 'well', 'goodness', 'Yeah'])

test_data = """RegExr Yeah was created by gskinner.com.
yippe, ow, ouch, gosh Yeah oh, goodness, oh well, oh no, how can I do wonders in this world. Yep, it is out of the world.
Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
"""
new_data = ' '.join(i for i in test_data.split() if (i and i not in words_to_remove))
print(new_data)
```

output

```
RegExr was created by gskinner.com. yippe, ow, ouch, oh, goodness, well, no, how can I do wonders in this world. Yep, it is out of the world. Edit the Expression & Text, to-see matches. Roll; over$ matches% or* the expr@ession for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode. The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
```

Comment: does not work with commas... as you can see in your own output.

Comment: @Julien ah got it, need to add filter criteria for word with non english character at start and at end